IF/THEN formula for Excel - based on subsection of the original value
I am looking for guidance on a formula that returns a section of a numerical value to the millionths decimal place value e.g 0.000000 based on the value of another cell in the workbook.
Example, =IF(B2<x.xx4999,return=0.004999,false) - in other words IF B2's value is any number with the thousandth, ten-thousandth, hundred-thousandth, and millionth decimal places that are less than x.xx4999, I want the formula to return any number that has the parameters from the thousandth, ten-thousandth, hundred-thousandth and millionth decimal point.
I don't care what the value is for any decimal point greater than the thousandth point.  To ensure full clarity, another example is let's say cell B2 has a value of 8,913,134.883499, I want the formula to return 0.003499; IF B2 has a value of 8,913,134.885001 I want the formula to return FALSE.
I am only interested in the smallest decimal points less then 0.004999 regardless of the value of the  larger points.  If the return value has to include all values for the entire numerical string that will work too, but ideally removing any value above the thousandth point.
I have yet to find any formula that fits my intention, but I am by no means an expert.
I would greatly appreciate any and all thoughts, expertise, guidance, or examples where others have done this successfully or something similar that perhaps I can modify if needed.

May be =LET(α,--REPLACE(ROUND(MOD(B2, 1),6),3,2,"00"), IF(α<0.004999, α, FALSE))

This works great as well, thank you!! :)

Here is an alternative way, as proposed in comments above by me:
=LET(α,--REPLACE(ROUND(MOD(B2, 1),6),3,2,"00"), IF(α<0.004999, α, FALSE))


Wasn't able to test it, since OP confirmed it worked, posted as an answer!

Try this
=let(value,B2*100,IF(value-int(value)<0.4999,(value-int(value))/100,false))

Whoops, I was going off the google-sheets tag and just saw the Excel part. Not every version of Excel has access to the let function, so you can use this as an alternate if need be.
=IF((B2*100)-int((B2*100))<0.4999,((B2*100)-int((B2*100)))/100,false)


Awesome. Drop an answered when you have time.

Similar to Kreeszh', encapsulating with a LAMBDA:
=LAMBDA(input, threshold,
    LET(
        thousandth_part, input * 100 - TRUNC(input * 100),
        IF(thousandth_part < threshold, thousandth_part / 100)
    )
)(C4:C13, 0.4999)


